# how to fix Chart.js bubble inner padding problem

Tags: chart.js

[How to fix this? chart.js 3.5.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mEUD.png)

[with small radius there are no padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGVqJ.png)

How remove chat inner plot padding? It shows when i have big bobble radius.

I try search in chart.js documentation, and in stack overflow but don't find solution
Unfortunately, the Chart JS documention on bubble charts is severely lacking as well.

```js
     options: {
                    animation: false,
                    onClick: (e, i) => {
                        if (i.length) {
                            const bubbleSelected = i[0];
                            wordsTopic = `Topic${bubbleSelected.datasetIndex + 1}`
                            aBarCh.changeCanvas({data:groupDataByTopics(JSONDATA),topic:wordsTopic})
                        } else {
                            wordsTopic = `Default`
                            aBarCh.changeCanvas({data:groupDataByTopics(JSONDATA),topic:wordsTopic})
                        }
                    },
                    onHover: (e, i) => {
                        if (i.length) {
                            const bubbleSelected = i[0];
                            if(wordsTopic !== `Topic${bubbleSelected.datasetIndex + 1}`){
                                aBarCh.changeCanvas({data:groupDataByTopics(JSONDATA),topic:`Topic${bubbleSelected.datasetIndex + 1}`})
                            }
                        } else {
                            aBarCh.changeCanvas({data:groupDataByTopics(JSONDATA),topic:wordsTopic})
                        }
                    },
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    layout: {
                        padding: 0
                    },
                    layout: {
                        padding: 0
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                        title: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                    },
                    scales: {
                        x: {
                            min: -0.25,
                            max: 0.25,
                            suggestedMin:-0.25,
                            suggestedMax:0.25,
                            ticks: {
                                color: '#fff',
                                padding: 0,
                            },
                            grid: {
                                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
                                color: function (context) {
                                    if (context.tick.value !== 0) {
                                        return 'transparent';
                                    }
                                    return 'rgba(78, 99, 102, 1)';
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        y: {
                            min: -0.25,
                            max: 0.25,
                            suggestedMin:-0.25,
                            suggestedMax:0.25,
                            ticks: {
                                color: '#fff',
                                padding: 0
                            },
                            grid: {
                                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
                                color: function (context) {
                                    if (context.tick.value !== 0) {
                                        return 'transparent';
                                    }
                                    return 'rgba(78, 99, 102, 1)';
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and adding this config to the chart's options solved the problem for me:

```
layout: {
  autoPadding: false,
},
```

Adding some inner padding to the axis overriding the min and max values could be also needed.

Comment: This makes no change for me.  Does anyone have any other ideas?